# Confusion about equality

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

I just wanted to know the correct explanation of the results

```js
// All of these evaluate to 'true'!
console.log(false == '0');
console.log(null == undefined);
console.log(" \t\r\n" == 0);
console.log('' == 0);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?v=control It pratically fully answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using == , it doesn't checks type, just the value.Internally, all these values are kind of false values.Hence it returns true.

However, using === will check type too and result to print false instead of true in console

Answer (score 0):

this is called type coercion.

when you use double equals (`==`) the parser try to coerce both the operands to achieve equality.

Most sources suggest using triple equals (`===`) because it doesn't apply any type coercion instead. if the values are of differet types that means they are not equals.

back to your question:

`null`, `empty string` and `0` are all falsey values, that means all are coerced to false. thus the equality check will go through.